# How to merge (audio-video) URL and merge video download at client side?

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs

I want to merge the youtube video link and audio link without a store in the local system.
It merges on the client and downloads the client-side.

I need a solution in a client-side language. like javascript, react js

Please help me.

Does anyone have a solution

Comment: Did you found any answer?

Comment: Not yet. @RoyalBosS